# Virtualbox: Windows 8.1 Host, Centos 6.6 Guest: No guest internet access

Tags: windows, virtualbox, centos

I'm moving to a new Win8.1 laptop (fully updated) with Virtualbox 4.3.20 installed, and my freshly-installed CentOS 6.6 guest (with Guest Additions installed) has no internet access.  This is my first experience with Win8.1 after a long time with Win7.

I have two VBox guest adapters: Adapter 2 is "Host-only" (for ssh, works fine), and Adapter 1 is "NAT" (needed mainly for yum).  All are configured for DHCP.  I've tried the various emulated hardware devices as well as virtio-net, with no observed differences in operation (virtio-net is presently selected for both adapters).

Update: When trying to ping an IP address (such as 8.8.8.8) from the guest, I get "connect: Network is unreachable"

The Win8.1 host has wired and WiFi adapters, with wired presently active.  On all adapters I've disabled "Client for Microsoft Networks" and "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" (for security reasons).  All are configured for DHCP.

Under Win7 I had installed various Linux guests (Ubuntu, Fedora), and guest networking always "just worked" without any extra setup or configuration required.

Searches yield solutions that all seem to match my current configuration, so I'm not sure what's not working or why.

What am I missing to get internet access working for the CentOS guest?  What are the minimum required configuration elements on the host and the guest?

Thanks!

EDIT: Clue #1: I just noticed that `eth0` had no IP address.  But while running `sudo dhclient eth0` did give it an IP address, it still doesn't see the Internet.

Comment: Check in VM edit settings whether assigned virtual adapter is internal or external switch connected. If internal try changing it to external and check.

Comment: I see no setting like what you describe.  Where is it?

Comment: Does it work if you set the Network Adapter to "Bridged Adapter" for the VM?

Comment: It won't let me do that: Claims it's an invalid configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If the guest able to get both host-only and NAT IP addresses correctly, the problem might be on the route table. Please check the output of "ip route" to find out what is the default route.

Comment: When I had first tried "ip route" yesterday, it was empty.  Now, suddenly, everything's working and I have the default route I expected.  I have no idea what the last thing was I did yesterday...  Once my present tasks complete, I'll restart the VM and see if the fix sticks.